# Will hosting same website in multiple domains (1 for testing and other for production) cause SEO/Adsense rejection issue?

Tags: google-search, google-adsense, seo

I would like to host two copies of same website under different domains.
The idea is to setup one for testing and other for production.
So will it cause SEO or duplicate content issue?

As far I know indexing can be disable by the following tag

So is it safe to deploy testing version site with noindex tag?

Because I doubt's even if indexing is disabled, still google can read the content.
So later will lead to rejection of Google adsense due to duplicate content ?

And please suggest the best method to achieve this?

(I don't have adsense now, but I may apply for it later)

Answer (score 1):

> So will it cause SEO or duplicate content issue?

Yes. SEO will be surely affected due to duplicate content. You should never keep test site content accessible without proper crawling policy (robots.txt). Different subdomain, Password protection or IP based access to test site are also more preferred way to avoid test site content crawled.

In case if you still need to test different version of content from different domain (or testing domain), you should use **canonical** tag to avoid SEO penalties of duplicate content.